# Check if two lists contain the same numbers using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I'd like to know if there is a better way (still using LINQ) of achieving the following, which checks that both this have the same numbers in them:

```
var list1 = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
var list2 = new int[] { 2, 1, 3, 4 };

return list1.Intersect(list2).Count() == list2.Count();
```

The above example would return `true`

Comment: Is `list1` just a substitution of `list2`? or it can contain more items?

Comment: Your method won't work if any elements are repeated in the input lists.

Comment: @KingKing Both lists must contain the same items (and the same number of items), but they may be in any order.

Comment: @Lee: Good call... Any ideas on ways to get around that?

Comment: @Jimbo: Does that mean that `AreTheSame({ 1 }, { 1, 1 })` should be `true`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use two `HashSet<int>` and the [`SetEquals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb346516.aspx) method:

```
var l1Lookup = new HashSet<int>(list1);
var l2Lookup = new HashSet<int>(list2);
bool containsSame = l1Lookup.SetEquals(l2Lookup);  // true
```

> The SetEquals method **ignores duplicate entries and the order of
>   elements** in the other parameter. If the collection represented by
>   other is a HashSet collection with the same equality comparer as
>   the current HashSet object, this method is an **O(n) operation**.
>   Otherwise, this method is an O(n + m) operation, where n is the number
>   of elements in other and m is Count.

Your `Count()` approach *can* be inefficient if the sequences are large or/and they are not a collection but an expensive query. It **can also be incorrect** since the count of all items is not necessarily the count of intersecting items since `Intersect` removes duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

I think this works but not sure it's efficient enough:

```
bool isEqual = list1.OrderBy(x=>x).SequenceEqual(list2.OrderBy(x=>x));
```

Comment: Cool idea :) I imagine the `SequenceEqual` uses short-circuit semantics and its efficient?

Comment: @Jimbo I'm not sure because I don't know the **internal implementation** of the query combination, however even without `LINQ`, this is a natural way to test.